# Powering up a 16x2 LCD display with only a 9V battery

Tags: lcd, battery, voltage, resistor, arduino-nano-33-iot

I'm using an Arduino (Nano 33 IoT) board for a project and apparently this board can only supply with 3.3 volts when a 9V battery is connected to it through Vin and GND pins. In other words, I'm powering the Arduino board with a 9V battery, but I want to power supply an LCD display through my Arduino, but I can't.

This Arduino board only has a 3.3 volts pin. It has a 5V pin but it's only enabled when the Arduino is powered by USB.

The problem: The LCD display only takes up to 5.5V, and its minimum required voltage is 4.5V. I cannot power it from the Arduino board because voltage is too low, and I cannot power it directly from the 9V battery because it's too high.

What can be done?

Note: I don't have a voltage regulator to use between the LCD and battery.

Is it possible to use voltage divider?

Note: The LCD screen that I'm using is connected to I2C protocol module. It has only 4 pins: SCL and SDA pins (connected to arduino), and 2 power pins (GND and VCC).

it should look like this when connected to a regular arduino uno:
[image: Figure 1: Arduino UNO with I2C LCD displaay]

What would the circuit look like if I desire to use voltage divider?

Or can I simply use just one resistor between the 9V battery positive pin and the LCD's positive power pin?

Comment: You can't use resistor, you need a regulator to bring the 9v down to 5V. BTW, how long do you expecting your 9V battery to last for? With WiFi (Nano 33 IoT has Wifi chip that could take up to 150mA during transmission), plus display, it won't last long.

Comment: To add to the list of problems that @hcheung started, you should consider if the LCD you have chosen is able to reliably operate while receiving what is likely a 0 to 3.3 volt data signal.  Some might, others may not. I2C is an open drain bus, but is it pulled up to 3.3 volts on the processor board?  Or is it pulled up to 5 volts on the LCD board? In the latter case, you need to instead ask if the processor is 5 volt tolerant.

Comment: ... follow up: I could put the above into an answer w/more details if you like.  But, if this were my project, I'd go out and buy an I2C LCD that is designed to work at 3.3 volts.  Otherwise some of the things you would need to do: Buy a 9 to 5 volt regulator, understand how an I2C bus works which might lead to removing SMD parts on the Nano 33 IoT PCB and / or might lead to adding parts to the LCD PCB.

Comment: your picture shows a UNO, that would work. Posting the correct frizzy picture would help. Best is to post an annotated schematic.

Comment: If it's important to you to have backlighting, you should probably say. Because that will have an impact on any answer you get.

Comment: Yeah, battery won't last long. I think if I turn off backlight it would make it last slightly longer. 

@st2000 I think that would be a good solution instead of buying a regulator. But most LCDs need 5V to work. If I find one with I2C bus which operates at 3.3, it would be the best solution.

Comment: Although it is effectively a 3.3 volt device, the nano 33 iot does have a 5v pin. Ideally, you would use an I2C compatible level shifter between the nano 33 iot and the LCD screen.